# XML Parsing Using EventReader, Storing separate Strings

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have the following XML (dumbed down for simplicity)

```
<object class="domain">
    <property>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
</object>
<object class="domain">
    <property>
        <value>10</value>
    </property>
</object>
<object class="domain">
    <object class="ID">
    </object>
    <object class="Extranet">
    </object>
</object>
```

As you can see I have several XML tags called object. What I want to do is iterate through the XML (currently using StAX) and save each separate object as a separate String (unless there is a better alternative when using XML) in a HashSet of String. I can easily find the start tag  using the following...

```
case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                StartElement startElement = (StartElement) event;
                QName elementStartName = startElement.getName();


                if(elementStartName.getLocalPart() == "object"){
                    for (Iterator it = startElement.getAttributes(); it.hasNext();) {
                        Attribute attr = (Attribute) it.next();
                        String currentAttr = attr.getName().toString();
                        String attrValue = attr.getValue();

                        if(attrValue.contains("domain") && currentAttr == "class"){
                            System.out.println(attrValue);
                        }
                    }
                }

                break;
```

But I do not know how to start reading just that bit of code enclosed between the two `<object class="domain">` and store it as a string, eventually to be closed out with `XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT`. I know this is very specific and missing many details, but if anyone has any high level ideas it would be appreciated.